# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Fast way to add lots of classpath variables at once

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, noclassdeffounderror, jface

I'm getting tons of errors when I try to run a baby SWT/JFace application. EEach error disappears - and is replaced by a new one - as soon as I go into the BuildPath and add a Variable to satisfy what the Error log is looking for. However, this is proving to take a lot of time, and I am wondering if I am doing this right? Is there a better way?

It doesn't make sense to me that I'd have to manually be telling Eclipse where to find all jar's it needs (like `org.eclipse.ui` and `org.eclipse.jface`). They are all right there in the plugins folder!

Here's a screenshot to give you an idea of what the errors look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your build path from Project->properties->Java Build Path -> Libraries , remove all your jars and again include the Jars in your build path . Project->Clean .. your project . This may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the SWT jar from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

And if still you are getting those ClassNotFound errors you need to put all the jars it asks for in  your classpath.